# Is there a way to send html emails with django-mailer?

Tags: python, django

I am developing a site using Django and Python.

I am using django-mailer to send out a newsletter to registered subscribers.  It can do text emails ok, but passing html into the send_mail function doesn't have the desired result.

Is it possible to use django-mailer to send html or otherwise is there a way I can adjust/modify/hack it to do what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Roam's answer pointed me in the right direction, but it wasn't a complete answer.

The real answer to this is that you can't normally send html emails with django-mailer.  It might be possible to hack django-mailer or work around it in someother way - but I haven't yet heard of any way of doing that.

The better alternative is to use `send_html_email` but this doesn't actually come with django-mailer, although it does come with pinax-django-mailer which is a fork of django-mailer, so mostly the same but with the addition of `send_html_email`.

If you have already installed django-mailer then you should make sure it is completely removed before attempting to install pinax-django-mailer otherwise you will encounter problems.  I had to go into my Python directory and manually remove django-mailer in order to then get pinax-django-mailer installed cleanly.

Assuming that you have properly removed django-mailer (or not installed it in the first place) then you will find it quite easy to get up an running with pinax-django-mailer.

Answer (score 3):

**edited**
Use django-mailer's `send_html_mail`. Have a look at the [usage.txt file in the django-mailer repo](https://github.com/pinax/django-mailer/blob/master/docs/usage.rst).

Comment: I did see that in the docs but it doesn't actually appear to exist in the mailer that I have installed.  Would it be possible that I have an old version installed?

Comment: I see it now, the project that you referred me to is a fork of the django-mailer that I am using.

Comment: Yes, that's probably an old version, because you can see the function in the current `__init__.py` of mailer module.

Comment: Well it is mystery to me where that send_html_email is supposed to come from, I uninstalled my existing django-mailer, then installed pinax-django-mailer (the one that has the doco you pointed me to) but still I was unable to find send_html_email.

Comment: I might have some kind of install issue now, because the __init__.py that I extracted from the zip is different to the one that is installed in my Python directory, and it does have send_html_mail.

Comment: Ok, so now that I have completely deleted the old 'mailer' installation and downloaded and installed pinax-django-mailer it appears to be working.  Thanks!

Comment: So last words on this: If you have django-mailer installed there is no send_html_mail.  This only exists if you have pinax-django-mailer intsalled. And if you have to uninstall django-mailer to change over to pinax-django-mailer you need to make sure that django-mailer is completely deleted from your Python directory!  Your answer pointed me in the right direction, but it's not quite complete.  If you can edit your answer based on my comments I'll be happy to mark it as the correct answer.  Otherwise I'll create my own answer.